# Python - Override parent class argument

Tags: python

I have a super class and a sub class.

```
class Vehicle:
   def __init__(self, new_fuel, new_position):
        self.fuel = new_fuel
        self.position = new_position

class Car(Vehicle):
   # Here, I am stating that when Car is initialized, the position will be 
   # at (0, 0), so when you call it, you do not have to give it a new_position argument 
    def __init__(self, new_fuel, new_position=(0, 0)):
        super(Car, self).__init__(new_fuel, new_position)
        self.new_position = new_position
```

**Problem:**

I want this to initialize a Car object with 10 fuel and position of (0, 0)
but I don't want to put in an argument for new_position because I've stated that when all cars are initialized, they have a position of (0, 0). Also, I don't want to change any arguments in the parent class (vehicle), I just want to override them within the sub classes (such as Car).

```
test_car = Car(10)
print(test_car.new_position)
>>> (0,0)
```

However, it keeps giving me this error and asks to put in an argument for new_position

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'new_position'
```

Comment: Please be sure you are running an exact copy of the code you posted

Comment: @MosesKoledoye note `new_position` is not the same as `position`, which is set in the superclass.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Didn't notice the difference. Yep, right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand what you are trying to achieve, just simply delete the "new_position" parameter from your Car __init__ method.

```
class Vehicle:
   def __init__(self, new_fuel, new_position):
        self.fuel = new_fuel
        self.position = new_position

class Car(Vehicle):
   # Here, I am stating that when Car is initialized, the position will be 
   # at (0, 0), so when you call it, you do not have to give it a new_position argument 
    def __init__(self, new_fuel):
        super(Car, self).__init__(new_fuel, new_position= (0, 0))
```

Later when any method from the Car class will need a "position" argument, it will search inside the Car class and when not found, it will jump into Vehicle and will find it.

Lets say that you've implemented get_position() method in your Vehicle class.

```
class Vehicle:
    <everything as always>

    def get_position(self):
        return self.position

class Car(Vehicle):
   <everything as always>

a = Car(10)
a.get_position() # Returns (0, 0)
```

## Edit to comment:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, new_fuel):
        self.fuel = new_fuel

    def get_position(self):
        return self.__class__.POSITION

class Car(Vehicle):
    POSITION = (0, 0)
    # Here, I am stating that when Car is initialized, the position will be 
    # at (0, 0), so when you call it, you do not have to give it a new_position argument 
    def __init__(self, new_fuel):
       super(Car, self).__init__(new_fuel)

    def new_position(self, value):
       self.__class__.POSITION = value

a = Car(10)
b = Car(20)
c = Car(30)

for each in [a, b, c]:
    print(each.get_position())
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
c.new_position((0, 1))
for each in [a, b, c]:
    print(each.get_position()) 
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
```

Comment: But I need for print(test_car.new_position) to output (0, 0). With this code, only print(test_car.position) outputs (0, 0).

Comment: I've edited my answer, but im not sure if you want this method (available only for Car) to return the same as self.position? If yes, this might be the way

Comment: Hmm, not quite, I don't want to make a method to return self.position. I want it to return position from the set value of new_position within init.

Comment: Reason being is, if I have multiple vehicles, say a Car, a Boat, etc. I want to be able to change some of the vehicles self.position values from the new_position argument within the sub classes. I want to do this through init.

Comment: So all you want to do is to be able to write: c = Car(10), c.new_position = (0, 1), and by that u want self.position to be changed into (0, 1)?

Comment: Yes, but I want all objects of Car to have the property new_position(0,1). So c.new_position = (0,1),  d.new_position = (0,1), etc.

Comment: Check it now. Instead of using self.position argument in get_position method, I'm delegating to the CLASS variable, by self.__class__.POSITION and in new_position()  Im changing the class variable tho.